# Install MySQL for Windows from .zip and reset root password

Tags: mysql, windows, password-recovery, mysql-5.7

I wanted to have on my PC (with Windows 8.1 x64) the MySQL server only, without Workbench or something. So I downloaded `.zip` archive from [dev.mysql.com/downloads](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). It's a download for Win64 on x86_64 version 5.7.9 (MySQL Community Server (GPL)).

I installed it as a Windows service, but there were no `mysql` database, only `information_schema`. So I executed this:

```
mysql_upgrade.exe --upgrade-system-tables
```

And `mysql` databases were created. But along with it something happened with root user, because I couldn't access `mysql` anymore.

So I decided to reset this suddenly appeared password (because I didn't have it before that). I founded the following solution in the official manual, I started the server like this:

```
mysqld.exe --skip-grant-tables --console
```

Then I opened `mysql` without password:

```
mysql.exe –u root
```

And then tried to reset the root password:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD(‘passhere');
```

But I got this error:

> ERROR 1131 (42000): You are using MySQL as an anonymous user and anonymous users are not allowed to change passwords".

What is this? How am I anonymous? All commands were executed in `cmd.exe` under the Administrator.

What should I do to reset the root password in this situation?

**Update 1:** I tried to check the current user:

```
SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();
```

That gives:

```
+--------+----------------+
| USER() | CURRENT_USER() |
+--------+----------------+
| root@  | @              |
+--------+----------------+
```

That's weird, because I started it like `mysql.exe -u root`.

Then I checked users table:

```
SELECT user FROM mysql.user;
```

That gives:

```
+-----------+
| user      |
+-----------+
| mysql.sys |
+-----------+
```

That's even more weird. Also there is no password field:

```
SELECT user, password FROM mysql.user;
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'

So I cannot change its password.

And I cannot create a new user:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passhere';
```

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the `--skip-grant-tables` option so it cannot execute this statement

Now I'm lost.

**Update 2:** I guess, I did everything wrong from the beginning. Apparently, I missed a `mysqld.exe --initialize` command somehow.

So, this is how I installed MySQL from .zip-archive, thanks to *@RolandoMySQLDBA*:

1. Unpack archive, prepare `my.ini`.
2. Execute `mysqld.exe --initialize`, get temporary password from the `.err` file.
3. Install MySQL as a service and run it

   ```
   mysqld --install MySQL --defaults-file="d:/path/to/mysql/my.ini"
   ```
4. Connect to it `mysql -u root -p` with temporary password.
5. Change the temporary password:

   ```
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NEWPASSWORD';
   ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you started `mysqld` with [--skip-grant-tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables), you cannot execute any standard [**GRANT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html), [**REVOKE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html), or [**SET PASSWORD**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html) commands. Notwithstanding, you can change the password of `root@localhost` as follows:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD(‘passhere') WHERE user='root' and host='localhost';
```

Then, restart mysqld and you are back in business.

As to you being anonymous, if you login right now and run

```
SELECT USER() HowYouAttemptedToLogin,CURRENT_USER() HowYouWereAllowedToLogin;
```

You will note that the `HowYouWereAllowedToLogin` will have an blank username and some host.

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

### UPDATE 2015-11-17 16:24 EST

The column known as `password` in `mysql.user` no longer exists in MySQL 5.7.

It was renamed `authentication_string`.

### Proper Approach

What you should have done is run

```
mysqld --initialize
```

That would create the data folder for you.

The root@localhost was assigned a temporary password, which is visible in the error file starting with the following datetime and string

```
2015-11-17T20:56:02.175980Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost:
```

You could log in with it and then run `ALTER USER`

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

See the MySQL 5.7 Documentation on [SET PASSWORD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, I'm aware of such restrictions. But these are the steps from MySQL's manual. And I tried to follow your instructions, please see my edited question.

Comment: There is no password column anymore in mysql.user, so this method will never work again. However, currently also the other methods (via --skip-grant-tables and --init-file) are broken, so you cannot reset passwords in 5.7.9 atm.

Comment: @MikeLischke Thank you. I need to delete this answer

Comment: @MikeLischke I just realized the `password` column was renamed `authentication_string`.

Comment: Well, actually modifying the user table directly is a thing of the past and will go away, but even using standard commands (like alter user) don't work because currently they are refused as you are considered being an anonymous user which is not allowed to issue those commands (if you started the server with --skip-grant-tables or --init-file). The --initialize option however is the right way to reset the root pw.

Comment: Yes, now it worked. I guess, I missed somehow a `mysqld --initialize` command. Thank you!