# Issue with root password when re-installing MySQL

Tags: mysql, installation

I've got an issue when re-installing MySQL on Windows 11. Particularly, when reconfiguring MySQL server, MySQL installer asked for the current root password but I didn't remember. I've tried to reset the password but I couldn't find MySQL under services.msc to stop to set the password. Can anyone tell me in what way I can fix this? Many thanks[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install MySQL for Windows from .zip and reset root password](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119450/install-mysql-for-windows-from-zip-and-reset-root-password)

Comment: I don't think it answers as in my case I re-installed MySQL using this link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/, then I chose the latter one to download